# How to refactor sleeping snail

Tags: java, unit-testing, refactoring

There are a lot of refactoring questions out there that someone may already answered. However, I decided to ask my own question. I am having trouble refactoring Thread.sleep(1000) to countdownlatch in the code snippet below. In taking a Software Testing class I came across a paper on, "Are test smells really harmful: A empirical study" and I wanted to learn more about the topic area. Can anyone please help me?

```
    try (Socket client = new Socket("localhost", connector.getLocalPort()))
    {
        OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream();
        for (ByteBuffer buffer : lease.getByteBuffers())
        {
            output.write(BufferUtil.toArray(buffer));
        }

        Parser parser = new Parser(byteBufferPool, new      Parser.Listener.Adapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onHeaders(HeadersFrame frame)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Close the connection just after
                    // receiving the response headers.
                    client.close();
                    closeLatch.countDown();
                }
                catch (IOException x)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeIOException(x);
                }
            }
        }, 4096, 8192);

        parseResponse(client, parser);

        // We need to give some time to the server to receive and process the TCP FIN.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Session session = sessionRef.get();
        Assert.assertTrue(session.isClosed());
        Assert.assertTrue(((HTTP2Session)session).isDisconnected());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid there is no escaping from the waits in any test level. Since there is no way for you to know when exactly the System under test will respond (and some times it just don't). But you can turn to [Explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) that are utilized in the UI testing. If you are not familiar with the concept - Explicit waits are intelligent waits that are confined to a particular response. Using explicit waits you are basically telling your test that there is a max amount of time to wait for X units (let's assume 50ms) of time before it gives up.

Aiming at a full answer - you can also create a [Worker thread](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/WorkerThreadPatterninJava.htm) that will handle the request and once it gets the response, will automatically wake up the thread with the test.

UPDATE:

Here is [Java example](http://www.softwaretestingmagazine.com/knowledge/unit-testing-in-java-a-sleeping-snail/) of Testing multithreaded access without sleeping

```
@Test
 public void     concurrentAccessFromMultipleThreads() throws Exception {
 final Counter counter = new Counter();

 final CountDownLatch   allThreadsComplete = #1
   new CountDownLatch(threads); #1

 final int callsPerThread = 100;
 final Set values = new HashSet();
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
 @Override
public void run() {
 for (int i = 0; i < callsPerThread; i++) {
   values.add(counter.getAndIncrement());
 }
 allThreadsComplete.countDown(); #2
 }
 };

 int threads = 10;
 for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
 new Thread(runnable).start();
}

 allThreadsComplete.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); #3

 int expectedNoOfValues = threads * callsPerThread;
 assertEquals(expectedNoOfValues, values.size());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think I was not clear in my post. What I want is a better approach that replaces the wasteful and unreliable Thread.sleep. The fundamental difference is that I want to make use of Java’s synchronization objects from the java.util.concurrent package to make the test thread immediately aware of when the worker threads have completed their work.

Comment: I've update the last part of my answer, it's exactly thread oriented. Hope this is what you're after.

Comment: @Paul please keep your question clean and remove the **thanks** comment. The site has clear policy of rating the answers - *up/down* and *mark as accepted*. Thanks.  I'll be glad to assist you further if u need it.